# How can I make sure my Linux sees one file, but the data is stored on multiple drives?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage, media-server

I'm currently making my server (on Ubuntu, non server variant) that is going to act as a home theater server that i am sharing with my friends. Now, it is going to start very small, I only have a 60gb SSD. This is for start up fine, but will fill up pretty quick (Thinking about 10/15 movies in 1080p quality). Now I use emby, this is mostly like PLEX, but not relevant in my eyes.

The current way I have it setup to upload files is an FTP server. My friends can only see one folder where they upload their movies. But here is where I get stuck.

This folder will only exist on the first SSD, but not the HDDS that will later follow. But I want to use this folder to let me and my friends upload the data, but then when I upload it, it distributes it on different HDDs. But when I open the folder, I can see all the data of the HDDS that are behind it. (Some kind of a tree storage system?)

I have not tried anything myself that is remotely close to what I want to achieve. Simple said, I am just stuck.

So my question here, does anyone have tips on how I should accomplish this idea, or do others have better ways to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the data is stored on multiple drives` -- Do you mean the same data exists on multiple drives at the same time (redundancy)? Do you require each disk to be readable on its own and contain complete files? (yet not necessarily all of them). Terms to research: JBOD, RAID 0, LVM, union mount, mhddfs.

Comment: No I wasnt talking about redundancy (it are only movies, I do not care if they get lost)

And thank you for the tips, ill check it out!

Comment: I went with mhddfs, it seems like the best option for me

Answer (score 0):

[LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) is a great tool to accomplish this. If you configure the folder to be on a partition on an LVM "logical volume", you can later add disks to the "volume group" and migrate the "logical volume" to whatever combination of disks you want, inside the volume group.

Comment: Sounds very prommesing, only i heard once that if 1 drive fails, all the data is gone? Do you know this?

Comment: Software Raid can also protect, if you have multiple disks with enough space. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/raiding-with-lvm-vs-mdraid-pros-and-cons for a comparison of techniques.